# facelets-taglib-jsf20-spring-3 missing

Tags: maven

Hi we used to include this dependency in our project

```
<repository>
    <id>org.springframework.security.taglibs.facelets</id>
    <url>http://spring-security-facelets-taglib.googlecode.com/svn/repo/</url>
</repository>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>facelets-taglib-jsf20-spring-3</artifactId>
    <version>0.5</version>
</dependency>
```

somehow it is gone now in maven repository. Does anybody know why and where it has gone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently the spring-security- facelets - taglib library was moved from GoogleCode to GitHub .

Google also provided the Maven repository and it was used in the projects.

Unfortunately the library has not yet been moved to another repository, but already we contacted the author, and will be placed in the central Maven repository in the coming days.